# HTML file in Android 4.0.4 WebView does not change when modified on the server

Tags: android, html, webview

When the html file is modified on the server, changes that were made, are shown in Android version 2.2 and Android version 2.3.3, but not in Android version 4.0.4. For example old text is displayed instead of new one.

My code is:

```
public class MywebviewActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.mywebview);
final Activity MywebviewActivity = this;        
  // Makes Progress bar Visible
  getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
  android.webkit.WebView wv = 
  (android.webkit.WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView); 
  wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {     
  public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
  {
   //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
      MywebviewActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
      MywebviewActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL      is loaded

  // Return the app name after finish loading
  if(progress == 100)
      MywebviewActivity.setTitle(R.string.web_app_name);
    }
  });

  wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
  wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
  wv.loadUrl("http://mypagename.com/android/server/app/ver10/page1.html");

}

public void onBackPressed() {
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear the cache before loading the WebView:

```
...
android.webkit.WebView wv = (android.webkit.WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
wv.clearCache(true);
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
...
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearCache(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a property in the `WebViewSettings` to not cache data:

```
wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```